# how to access android files /data/anr/traces.txt and /data/tombstones/tombstones

Tags: android, tombstone

I am writing an application for reporting crashes and the relevant logs.
So from my application I am trying to access **traces.txt** and tombstones, but I am getting an error:

```
03-25 09:48:46.220 W/System.err(10250): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/tombstone/tombstone_00 (Permission denied)
```

I am able to access **traces.txt**, but not tombstones.

Comment: Did you use the [READ_LOGS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_LOGS) permission?

Answer (score 40):

You can use adb tool located in your_sd_root_dir/tools. Use it like this

```
./adb pull path_to_file location_to_save
```

Comment: thanks Mojo but,I want to do it from my android application.

Comment: I am not able to pull contents of /data/tombstones using this method. adb says permission denied

Comment: wouldn't this only work in the emulator?

Comment: It should work as root as well.

Answer (score 30):

You can capture a full bug report in Developer Options (see [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/bug-report.html)). In the bug report's ZIP file, you can find `tombstones` and `anr` folders in `/FS/data`.

This will work with rooted and unrooted devices.

Comment: unroot devices finnaly got /data/tombstones/ by `adb bugreport`. // android 10.
// BTW `adb pull` or `adb shell` no permissions.

Comment: adb bugreport is the only way works for unrooted Android 10+ version phones. It will show permissions deny when using adb pull or cp to /sdcard/ folder.

Answer (score 26):

If you get "permission denied" you can do this:

```
adb shell "cp /data/anr/traces.txt /storage/extSdCard/" 
adb pull /storage/extSdCard/traces.txt
```

Comment: I get No such file or directory when I execute `adb shell "cp /data/anr/traces.txt /storage/extSdCard/" ` and I get permission denied on adb shell `"cp /data/tombstones/traces.txt /storage/extSdCard/"`

Comment: @mundella Find an intermediate directory that works for you -- I use `/sdcard/`, and rename the file, so my script looks like:  `adb shell "cp /data/anr/traces.txt /sdcard/anr_trace.txt" ; 
adb pull /sdcard/anr_trace.txt`

Comment: I get an error: `permission denied`

Comment: still get permission denied

Answer (score 14):

> <sup>**Note:** This only works with android emulators and rooted android devices.</sup>

You can first check if the file is created or not. You can do this by going in

`DDMS -> File Explorer -> data -> data -> (Your Package) -> files -> (Your File)`

DDMS is on right top corner of your eclipse. If the file is not present in the above mentioned path then it is not created properly but if it is still there change the path your file accordingly while accessing it eg. `/data/data/(Your Package)/traces.txt`

You can also pull that traces.txt file onto your desktop. Pull option is given on top bar below DDMS.

Comment: Here are a few pictures depicting the same.. http://sree.cc/google/file-explorer-for-android-in-eclipse-ide

Comment: thanks Harshad but ,I want to do it from my android application.

Comment: are you able to see traces.txt at above mentioned location?? If you are able to see it then i suggest you to correct your path where you are accessing it.

Comment: Hi Harshad, traces.txt has permission -rw-rw-rw so im able to access this file :) , but how i can now access /data/tombstones/

Comment: wouldn't this only work in the emulator?

Comment: @CQM Yes. It will show only for emulator.

Comment: It may show up only when you are root (on the device).

Comment: Awesome tip! Pulling data from adb is a bit of hassle.

Comment: i see logcat message: Stack trace written to: /data/anr/traces.txt , but the /data directory itself appears to be empty in File Explorer view. Any idea?

Comment: Cannot expand `data` directory in DDMS file explorer.

Answer (score 12):

This did it for me: adb pull "/data/anr/traces.txt"

Comment: Confirmed working without root on S8+. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

```
adb shell "cd /data/anr && cat traces.txt" > anr.txt
```

This will copy traces.txt in anr.txt in your current set directory

Comment: This is very useful.

Comment: still get `permission denied`

Comment: Can anyone please help me in this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62008671/how-to-get-anr-stack-trace-file-from-non-rooted-device-on-android-q) as non of the available answer solves

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the file you need via DropBoxManager class
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/DropBoxManager.html

The tombstone file is also copied to dropbox (at least on emulator)

Comment: would would be the values for tag and msec in getNextEntry to get the contents of /data/anr/traces.txt ?

Comment: The values would be something like this getNextEntry("SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE", before). Unfortunately this throws an Exception unless you are signed with the system key.

Answer (score 1):

Adb shell data/system/Dropbox then use ls to view files generated  inside Dropbox iinside dropbox you will get crashes,anr and traces file

If you want access them create folder and open adb inside that folder and use following command adb pull data/system/dropbox

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, I'd seen logcat prints about the DropBox being updated whenever a tombstone is generated, but never realized we could use this in the app. Works great, saved a lot a headaches that I'd have to deal with se-policies!!