# How to get android application traces.txt file from android device

Tags: android

I want to get the my application traces.txt file from the android device. I check lots of the link in the google, but still not get success. If any one have any idea, please help me.
I also check the below link.
    [how to access android files /data/anr/traces.txt and /data/tombstones/tombstones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467972/how-to-access-android-files-data-anr-traces-txt-and-data-tombstones-tombstones)
    [How to find this stack trace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680397/how-to-find-this-stack-trace)

I am also trying this.
    adb -s 0123456789ABCDEF shell # <<< This will open a shell to your device

```
ps | grep com.package.name # This will list some info about the running         instance of your app
# Output should be something like: 
# u0_a7    18941 173   869348 26040 ffffffff 00000000 S    com.package.name
# Important is the PID (number in the second column), in this case 18941.

# Now send the SIGQUIT to your process, please change '18941' to your PID
run-as com.package.name kill -3 18941

# Now Android should have created the file /data/anr/traces.txt, check that:
ls -l /data/anr/traces.txt 
# Output should be something like
# -rw-rw-rw- system   system     325391 2014-02-03 14:11 traces.txt

# And finally pull that file
exit
```

adb -s 0123456789ABCDEF pull /data/anr/traces.txt

but I am getting the this error "run-as: Package 'com.package.name' has corrupt installation."

Comment: In Physical device you cannot get this traces.txt untill  your device is rooted.

Answer (score 15):

You can do the same thing using adb:

```
adb pull /data/anr/traces.txt
```

Comment: but how to add package name with this commands?.

Comment: connect ur device with PC and run command, this traces file will copied on to the platform-tools directory

Comment: Its default path of traces.txt file for all the Application

Comment: but its showing this "failed to copy '/data/anr/traces.txt' to './traces.txt': Permission denied".

Comment: just try this adb shell ---> cd data/anr and than cat traces.txt

Comment: by doing this you can also read file.

Comment: please check this, $ adb shell
shell@android:/ $ cd data
cd data
shell@android:/data $ cd anr
cd anr
shell@android:/data/anr $ cat traces.txt
cat traces.txt
/system/bin/sh: cat: traces.txt: Permission denied
1|shell@android:/data/anr $

Comment: Run this command ls -l traces.txt inside data.anr and check what are the permission you have for traces.txt

Comment: 127|shell@android:/data/anr $ ls -l traces.txt
ls -l traces.txt
-rw------- system   system          0 2014-02-03 12:07 traces.txt
shell@android:/data/anr $

Comment: above commands shows the rw permission.

Comment: what best you can do just unplug and plug again your device with PC and try ;)

Comment: or just delete this file by using rm -r traces.txt and regenerate file once again

Comment: again permission denied,"$ adb shell
shell@android:/ $ cd data
cd data
shell@android:/data $ cd anr
cd anr
shell@android:/data/anr $ rm -r traces.txt
rm -r traces.txt
rm failed for traces.txt, Permission denied
"

Comment: sorry for downvote, I did it by mistake. will cancel it after answer will be edited. It is very useful answer for me

Comment: I removed traces.txt file and I was thinking that it will be generated again but it did not. How would I achieve that file again?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
// start tracing to "/sdcard/calc.trace"
Debug.startMethodTracing("Name of yours");
// ...
// stop tracing
Debug.stopMethodTracing();
```

it will store the trace details in the SDCArd

for more details see the below link

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html

Answer (score 0):

You can get traces.txt from non-rooted physical devices as well. You need to copy it on sdcard (or any accessible location on your device), and then copy it from there. Open your terminal and follow these steps:

```
./adb shell
cat /data/anr/traces.txt.bugreport  > /sdcard/traces.txt
./adb pull /sdcard/traces.txt
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

This will copy traces.txt in anr.txt in your current set directory

```
adb shell "cd /data/anr && cat traces.txt" > anr.txt
```